How correctly to bind a Linux server on Active Directory using vSphere customization script?
To deploy new Linux server on our infrastructure we have an Ubuntu Server template in vSphere that we clone and wants to customize using the built-in vSphere mechanism.
Using this system we wants to run a script that will customize the VM, and especially will bind it to our Active Directory so admin access to our server are link to our named admin account and so already using our public SSH key published via the directory service.
To bind the VM to our domain we use the following command:
 echo "TotoPassword" | realm join --user "toto" --computer-ou "OU=Other,OU=Managed Servers,DC=corp,DC=example,DC=com" --os-name "Ubuntu Server" corp.example.com

Which works as expected when run interactively:

the server is bound
A and PTR records are created for <VM name>.corp.example.com
authentication works

But when run via the customization process of vSphere, it all works except that A and PTR are created for <VM name>..
The domain name is missing and that's what I try to solve here.
There is multiple stage in the vSphere process, we have it on the postcustomization (and other tasks of this stage works OK too).
